# Integer promotion for `long` and `size_t` when sent through ellipsis?

Tags: c, integer-promotion

View this question from the perspective of someone implementing `printf`.

Since the arguments of `printf` are passed through an ellipsis (`...`), they get integer promoted. I know that `char`, `short` and `int` get promoted to `int` while `long long` does not get promoted. Similarly for their `unsigned` counterparts.

This implies that when reading the varargs, `va_arg(args, int)` should be used for `char`, `short` and `int` while `va_arg(args, long long)` should be used for `long long`.

My question is, do `long` and `size_t` get promoted, and if they do, to what? There are many sources on the internet on integer promotion, but I haven't seen any that talk about these types.

P.S. I would appreciate a reference to the standard.

Comment: you might be interested in [PDCLib](http://pdclib.e43.eu/), which, however, doesn't handle the edge cases in their [printf implementation](http://hg.pdclib.e43.eu/pdclib/src/f72d72f131b1/functions/_PDCLIB/print.c?at=default#cl-465)

Comment: With reference to the issues below about doing it portably, note that it's *not* a goal of the standard to ensure that even simple standard library functions necessarily can be implemented portably. For example, there's no way to implement `memmove` portably without making two passes over the data, because pointers can't be compared unless they're within the same object. So no sensible implementation of `memmove` is entirely portable (for that and other reasons).

Comment: @SteveJessop: I think one could design a single-pass `memmove` if it starts by doing an upward copy but, before writing to each address, it compares it do the start of the source and--upon discovering a match--copies the remainder of the data in reverse order.  On at least some machines that might be faster than a full two-pass operation, though the proper remedy of course would be for the standard to define a `__UNRELATED_POINTER_COMPARE` macro which would indicate what if anything the implementation could promise about unrelated pointer comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integer conversion rank of `long` is required to be greater than the rank of `int` (6.3.1.1p1), so `va_arg(args, long)` is required *even if* `long` has the same representation (and precision) as `int`.  Note that on most 64-bit platforms, `long` is 64-bit; Windows (an LLP64 platform) is an exception.

`size_t` is required to be an unsigned integer type (6.5.3.4p5, 7.19p2) and is recommended to have an integer conversion rank no greater than that of `long int` (7.19p4); it is required to have a precision of at least 16 bits (7.20.3p2, minimum value of `SIZE_MAX`).  It is not required to be a (typedef to a) standard integer type, although it is allowed to be.

There are then three possibilities for the integer conversion rank of `size_t`:

1. It is less than that of `int`, so a `size_t` argument will be promoted to either `int` (if the precision of `size_t` is less than that of `int`) or `unsigned int` (if the two types have the same precision).  In either case you would need to write `va_arg(args, unsigned int)` (even if the `size_t` argument is promoted to `int`, using the equivalent unsigned type is allowed by 7.16.1.1p2).
2. It is the same as that of `int`, i.e. `size_t` is the same type as `unsigned int`.  In this case either `va_arg(args, unsigned int)` or `va_arg(args, size_t)` are allowed.
3. It is greater than that of `int`.  In this case `va_arg(args, size_t)` must be used.

Note that either of 1 and 3 can obtain even if the precision of `size_t` is the same as that of `int`.

This means that to extract a `size_t` parameter using `va_arg`, it is necessary to know or infer the integer conversion rank of `size_t`.  This can be done using a type-generic macro (6.5.1.1):

```
#define va_arg_size_t(args) _Generic((+(sizeof(0))),       \
  int:          (size_t) va_arg((args), unsigned int),     \
  unsigned int: (size_t) va_arg((args), unsigned int),     \
  default:               va_arg((args), size_t))
```

If `size_t` is promoted to `int` by the unary plus operator as used above, then we extract an `unsigned int`; if `size_t` is promoted to `unsigned int`, or is a typedef to `unsigned int`, then we extract an `unsigned int`; if it is not promoted and is a distinct type from `unsigned int`, then we hit the `default` block.  We can't supply `size_t` itself as an option, as that would conflict if `size_t` were a typedef for `unsigned int`.

Note that this is a problem not restricted to `size_t`, `ptrdiff_t` and `wchar_t` have the same issue (for the latter, `wint_t` can hold any `wchar_t` value and is not subject to promotion, but there is no guarantee that `wchar_t` *is* promoted to `wint_t`, unlike the guarantee that `char` is promoted to `int`).  I'd suggest that the standard needs to introduce new types `spromo_t`, `ppromo_t` and `wpromo_t`, and similarly for the types in `stdint.h`.  (Sure, you can use `_Generic` as above, but it's a pain in the neck.)

Comment: *It is not required to be a (typedef to a) standard integer type, although it is allowed to be.* in DR#067 C Committee says that size_t must be one of the standard integer types http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_067.html

Comment: @ouah 6.2.5p6 says that the extended integer types are included in the integer types.  If the standard intended `size_t` to be a standard integer type, they've had 20 years since that defect report to change the language in 6.5.3.4p5 and 7.19p2.

Comment: Rationale of C99 also says *The type of sizeof, whatever it is, is published (in the library header <stddef.h>) as size_t, since it is useful for the programmer to be able to refer to this type. This requirement implicitly restricts size_t to be a synonym for an existing unsigned integer type.*

Comment: @ouah: if any unsigned extended integer types exist in the implementation, then they are existing unsigned integer types. "Existing" means it's a typedef, `<stddef.h>` doesn't introduce another type. 6.5.3.4/4 couldn't be much clearer, `size_t` is "an unsigned integer type". Not (necessarily) a *standard* unsigned integer type. The same language is used to say what `uintmax_t` is, so if C99 intended to require `size_t` be a standard type then it has failed to actually say so. Unless `uintmax_t` likewise must be a standard type, and hence is the same size as `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @ouah that *still* doesn't say that `size_t` is a standard integer.  It doesn't matter, though; `size_t` could be `unsigned short`, with lesser or equal precision to `int`.

Comment: By rereading C90 I'm actually wondering what type DR#067 is referring to as there is no extended integer type in C90.

Comment: @ouah: For that matter there's no chapter 6 in C89, so I guess it refers to an early draft of C99, and the response applies similarly. Seems to me that C99 eventually added text to bring such types *into* the scope of the standard, and goes out of its way to state that the list of standard integer types is *not* an exhaustive list of integer types. This contrasts with the DR response.

Comment: I believe `if (sizeof(size_t) < sizeof(unsigned)) var = va_arg(args, unsigned); else var = va_arg(args, size_t);` should do the trick just fine, as the compiler evaluates the condition and omits the unnecessary part. Your macro seems a bit dodgy. Shouldn't you be including cases where `size_t` has a rank _smaller_ than `int`, instead of `int` itself?

Comment: @Shahbaz `size_t` could be a type the same size as `unsigned` but having a lesser integer conversion rank (e.g. `unsigned short`, on a platform where `short` and `int` have the same precision, or an extended integer type). In my macro, I'm applying unary plus to the `sizeof` expression, so it will be promoted to `int` (or `unsigned`) if appropriate.  (In other words, I'm observing how or if a `size_t` value is promoted, under controlled conditions.)

Answer (score 2):

C says (emphasis mine):

> (C99, 6.3.1.1p2) " The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may be used:
>
> — An object or expression with an integer type whose integer conversion rank is less
>   than or equal to the rank of int and unsigned int.
>
> — A bit-field of type _Bool, int, signed int, or unsigned int.
>
> If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions.48) **All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.**"

Comment: the conversions only apply for types with integer conversion rank less or equal to the rank of `int`, which is not part of the quote

Comment: @Christoph *All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.* This means the integer promotions only apply to values of integer type of rank less than `int` and `unsigned int` and that no change occurs for the other types.

Comment: re-read the first sentence - without the precondition, even types of greater conversion rank would be converted to `unsigned int`

Comment: @Christoph OK I will paste the whole quote

Comment: @litb size_t is a typedef for an unsigned integer type but I don't know any platform with size_t an alias for an unsigned integer type with a rank less than int.

Answer (score 1):

Arguments of type `long` won't be promoted. The integer promotions relevant to `size_t` can be summarized as follows:

1. if `size_t` is in range of `int`, promote to `int`
2. if `size_t` is in range of `unsigned int`, promote to `unsigned int`
3. otherwise, `size_t` has greater conversion rank (and thus width) than `unsigned int` and no promotion happens

The trivial case is if `size_t` is an alias for or has greater width than `unsigned int`. In these cases, no promotions happen and you can use `size_t` to read the variadic argument.

The edge cases are

- `size_t` is in range of `int`
- `size_t` is not in range of `int`, but in range of `unsigned int` without actually being `unsigned int`

The latter can happen if `int` contains padding of if `size_t` is an extended integer type of same width as `unsigned int`.

Assuming integer representations do *not* contain padding bits, you can cover both edge cases by reading an `unsigned int` variadic argument, which will work on all reasonable implementations of the C language despite possibly being undefined behaviour.

Comment: C11, 7.19.2: _`size_t` which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator_. I think we can safely assume that `size_t` is an `unsigned` type.